# Не правильная работа сессии

Tags: php

**При входе в аккаунт:** я задаю `$_SESSION['authorized'] = 1;`

**При выходе с аккаунта:**

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('private');
session_cache_expire(2592000); // 5 лет в минутах / кеширование на 5 лет в сессии
session_start();

setcookie('login', $login, time() - 3600);
setcookie('password', $password, time() - 3600);

$_SESSION['authorized'] = 0;

unset($_COOKIE['login']);
unset($_COOKIE['password']);

unset($_SESSION['authorized']);
unset($_SESSION['login']);

session_unset(); 
session_destroy();
header("location:../index.php");
?>
```

Здесь я удаляю сессию, и он выкидывает на главную страницу с надписью, что я не авторизован. Но при этом - это работает только по такому алгоритму. То есть, если я в ручную введу адрес то он выдаст его даже не авторизованному пользователю.

Пример такой страницы, где доступ должен быть только авториз пользователю:

```
<?
session_cache_limiter('private');
session_cache_expire(2592000); // 5 лет в минутах / кеширование на 5 лет в сессии
session_start();
include '/db.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Личный кабинет</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/personalAccount.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<? 
if ( $_SESSION['authorized'] = 1 ) {
// Здесь доступ только авторизованным пользователям 
} else {
// Здесь доступ не авторизованным
} 
?>
</body>
</head>
```

Вроде при авторизации = 1, при выходе = 0, а все равно показывает страничку кому попало, не могу понять, в чем дело? о.о

Comment: не    if ( $_SESSION['authorized'] = 1 ) { а if ( $_SESSION['authorized'] = =1 ) {

Comment: @sterx а, увидел, просто знака = нет, есть ==, вижу, сейчас попробую

Comment: оооо
про операторы знаете что нибудь? в вашем случае идет присваивание значения, а не сравнение переменной сессии с числом..

Comment: @sterx мои ошибки новичка :) Все работает) Спасибо

Comment: для неавторизованных - пробуйте в другом браузере для начала. если сработает - проверяйте, работает ли logout (сброс переменных сессии)